# Getting additional user claims for Google Authentication in Dotnet Core

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth

I would like to authenticate some users that are in our GSuite organisation and get some additional information such as either the Organisational Unit or if they are a member of a certain group.

I've tried a lot of options, but the promising one is from here: [Asp.Net Core google-signin oauth restrict access and get g-suite roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997458/asp-net-core-google-signin-oauth-restrict-access-and-get-g-suite-roles?rq=1)

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
    {
        Scope =
        {   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain.readonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly"
        },
        ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
        ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"],
        Events = new OAuthEvents()
        {
            OnTicketReceived = e =>
            {
                var claims = e.Principal.Claims;
                // Set breakpoint here and examine claims.
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    });
```

I have enabled the admin SDK & in my oAuth consent screen configuration, I added the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain.readonly` and 
            `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly` (this step felt wrong)

When I sign in using Google, I am asked to confirm that my application should have access to the additional claims, but when I examine the claims in `OnTicketReceived`, there are no additional claims.

I've also tried adding the birthday claim as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1#how-to-add-additional-custom-tokens but there is no difference in the claims that I can see.

Looking at this: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration it appears that there are only a very small number of claims supported